# I know the difference between apart and a part but i think apart here in this sentence doesnt make any sense it should've been a part

Tags: word-usage

[image: screenshot of some text]

> 10. You find out that your EX has had more children other than yours with him by other people, although you are a step parent, your actions with your child is...
>       __ Your child will be apart of all the siblings lives.
>       __ You say hell no my child won't be apart of those kids life.

I know the difference between apart and a part but i think apart here in this sentence doesn't make any sense it should've been a part

Comment: You're right, it's a mistake.

Comment: Firstly, please don't post pictures of text.  Just post the text itself.  But more importantly, the English in the question and the answers is TERRIBLE.  Whatever this is, throw it out and find a better place to learn English.

Comment: I upvoted @stangdon's comment but I have to emphasize that there are many problems in that text. I wouldn't use anything on that quiz as an example for your own writing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that `apart of` even exists, see [the definition of apart](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/apart).

`a part of` on the other hand does exist, see [the definition of part](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/part).

So there is probably only a space between `a` and `part` missing.